# why does "return" doesn't work the same as "console.log()"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So basically, I'm just trying to add 100 to the elements of the array `test` that are divisible by 3 and print out the `test` array. What I don't understand is that when I use `console.log(test)` in the function, it prints out the array with the condition met ie 100 is added to the elements that are divisible by 3, but when I use it outside of the function, it doesn't. Why is that? And is there a way to print out the test array with the condition met outside the function? I just started learning javascript, so I'm kinda a beginner.

```
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

test.forEach(function(test){
    if(test % 3 === 0){
        test+=100;
    }
    console.log(test);//prints out test array if condition met
});

//console.log(test); //doesn't print test array with if condition met????
```

Comment: You need to store back the updated value to your array, which you are not doing. For your case, you can use `array#map`.

Comment: `forEach` doesn’t change the array, and returning a value from the function you pass to `forEach` doesn’t do anything.

Comment: Your variable array test and elements are also named test. It would be a good idea to call the array tests with an s

Comment: lfender6445 that's a good point, but it doesn't really solve my problem :/.

Comment: Ryan okay, but how can I return the value in the function to use it outside of it?

Comment: Hassan Imam `array#map` ??

Comment: @Phil That won't work, OP wants the whole `test` array adding 100 to the numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado right you are. I misread the intent of the code

Comment: @BlueEagle please read the original question I linked, it shows how to use `forEach` to change the array in place. If you want to use `map`, it will return a new array. Here is a very verbose code, for you to see how to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/gmzm51hw/

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm reading them now. I'm actually reading both @Mamun answer and the answer you sent through the link to understand how the `for each` works and the array.map you sent. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` method does not directly modify the original array, but the callback function might modify it. The callback is passed with the element, the index, and the array itself.

```js
var test = [12, 929, 11, 3, 199, 1000, 7, 1, 24, 37, 4,
    19, 300, 3775, 299, 36, 209, 148, 169, 299,
    6, 109, 20, 58, 139, 59, 3, 1, 139
];

test.forEach(function(item, index, test){
    if(item % 3 === 0){
        test[index] = item+=100;
    }
});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: It works, but does the function's parameters has to be in a specific order?because when I did this `function(test,item,index)`, the code didn't work.

Comment: @BlueEagle, yes of course, all the parameters has to be in specific order. First one indicates the `current item` of the `iteration`, second one is for `index` and the third one is for the `original array`.